# Proof that if $A$ is open, then int$(\bar{A})=A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, self-learning

I am sure this is really a trivial result, but I would like to check my proving skills (plus I find it is sort of related to nowhere dense sets, that are quite difficult for me to digest.

> ***Proposition:***
>
> Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space. If $A \in \tau$, then int$(\bar{A}) = A$.
>
> *Proof:*
>
> - (only if)
>   Assume that $x \notin A$, and let $G \in \tau$ be arbitrary and such that $G \subseteq \bar{A}$. Assume by contradiction that $x \in G$. Then, we reach a contradiction because $x \in G \subseteq \bar{A}$ with $G \in \tau$, and $x \notin A$, where $A$ is the largest open subset of $\bar{A}$.
> - (if)
>   Assume that $x \notin \text{int}(\bar{A})$. Hence, for all $G \in \tau$, if $G \subseteq \bar{A}$, then $x \notin G$. Thus, $A \subseteq \bar{A}$ implies $x \notin A$ and the result is established.

Of course, as always any feedback is most welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The claimed result is not true. If $A$ is open, then $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A})$ can be a proper superset of $A$. Consider $A = (-1,0) \cup (0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot! Just to be sure I got it. The point of your example is that $\bar{A}=[-1, 1]$, and int$(\bar{A})=(-1, 1)$. Right? But then, what is the problem with my proof, that is where is the actual flaw?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. My first problem with your proof is that I don't know what you're trying to prove in each part. What do "only if" and "if" mean here? If you label the steps with what you're trying to prove, e.g. $A\in \tau \implies A = \operatorname{int}(\overline{A})$ and $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A}) \implies A \in \tau$, it is clear what the part is intended to show, and it is easier to identify the misunderstandings.

Comment: Your error is where you claim "where $A$ is the largest open subset of $\bar A$". That's basically claiming what you try to prove.

Comment: @DanielFischer: It is interesting you point out this *if/onlyif* issue, because I always found it a bit tricky, because given $P$ iff $Q$, then if $P$ then $Q$ means that $P$ is sufficient for $Q$, but if we look at the other direction is the other way around. Still, I noticed (maybe it is a convention) that **only if** is associated with the necessary condition and with the $\Rightarrow$ direction, while the **if** works the other way around. Thus, for example, In this specific case, only if stands for $x \in$ int$(\bar{A}) \Rightarrow x \in A$ proven by contraposition.

Comment: @celtschk: Thanks a lot. Now I see the problem, in particular in connection to the example of DanielFischer.

Comment: The sets such that $A = \mathrm{int}(\overline{A})$ are called *regularly open* or *regular open*. In a regular space, they form an open base.